# How to match start and end tag and anything between them including white space using regex?

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress

I have html content stored in my database and what i need to do is that i have to get this content and match for anchor tag and replace that anchor tag with any string.

Let say I have following html stored in my wordpress database.

```html
      <h3>Complications</h3>
      <p><strong>The three most common serious gastric sleeve complications</strong> are:</p>
      <ul>
         <li>
         <a href="https://insights.ovid.com/pubmed?pmid=28938270" target="_blank">3</a>
            <span><a href="javascript:;" class="list_expand">Staple line leaks</a> -  2.1% of patients on average (between 1.09% and 4.66%, depending on the study) experience staple line leaks (<a href="#reference-box">9</a>) (<a href="#reference-box">10</a>)</span>
            <div class="list_expand_content blockquote"></div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <span><a href="javascript:;" class="list_expand">Bleeding</a> - 1.2% of patients (<a href="#reference-box">11</a>)</span>
            <div class="list_expand_content blockquote"></div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <span><a href="javascript:;" class="list_expand">Stenosis/Strictures</a> -  0.6% of patients (<a href="#reference-box">12</a>)</span>
            <div class="list_expand_content blockquote"></div>
         </li>
      </ul>
```

and what i need to do is that I have to match anchor tag which is like

```
<a anthing goes here>[0-999]</a>
```

and replace that anchor tag with shortcode like [ref link= 'link which is wrapped inside each anchor tag' number='number wrapped between starting and closing anchor tag'].

I wrote following code for match the value and get the value.

`preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+>(\d{1,3})<\/a>/',$content,$matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`

but what about replacing that value with shortcode in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this regular expression: [`<a[^>]+href="([^"]+?)"[^>]+>(\d{1,3})<\/a>`](https://regex101.com/r/JKZsBP/2)

With this substitution: `[ref link='$1' number='$2']`

As you can see, this replaces:

```
<a href="https://insights.ovid.com/pubmed?pmid=28938270" target="_blank">3</a>
```

With this:

```
[ref link='https://insights.ovid.com/pubmed?pmid=28938270' number='3']
```

You can read about capture groups and backreferences [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

Comment: U mean to say that $1 will have link value and $2 will have numbers?

Comment: @David can u help me with one wordpress problem ?

Comment: @Krishnathakor Maybe. I haven't had any experience with wordpress myself. I think you'd be better off posting a new question on SO to try and get people who know wordpress to help you. You can post the question in a comment here, and I'll try to help :)

Comment: I think I need to post new question. Thanks.@David

Answer (score 0):

my answer would be like this.

```
$output = preg_replace_callback('/<a([^>]+)>\d{1,3}<\/a>/',function($matches) { return '[ref '.$matches[1].']'; }, $content);
```